# Rename Multiple MySQL Columns With Regex Possible?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql database with multiple tables that have column names like somename_fr for storing translations in different languages.

I need to rename them to somename_fr_CA, so just tack on the _CA part.

Is this possible to do with a query that will update them all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$tableFields = array();
$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM mytable");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if(substr($row['Field'], -3) == "_fr") {
            mysql_query("alter table tablename change `".$row['Field']."` `".$row['Field']."_CA`) ;
        }
    }
}
```

Why would you use regular expression? Simply use the `SHOW COLUMNS` query and loop the results and find out what table names need to be renamed and execute the query. In the loop I use substr to take the last 3 characters of the fieldname, if they equal "_fr" then an additional SQL query is fired: `ALTER TABLE`.

Resources:

1. list mysql table fields http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-fields.php
2. substr() http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php mysql
3. alter table: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Comment: Thanks! Designer here, so limited knowledge and thought regex to pattern match.